# missing files in my pip project after upload

Tags: python, package, pypi, python-packaging

Codes : https://github.com/rdvnszn1/TaPyFi

Pypi : https://pypi.org/project/tapyfi/

I want to share my package  and make some try however, I encounter a problem.

After upload my package with

`twine upload dist/*`

My files does not go totally to pip

I install it in other project and look at the files , see just  init and main file uploaded.

files in my other project

https://prnt.sc/qmw8x7

Answer (score 1):

Either list all packages and sub-packages in the argument to the `packages` parameter of the `setuptools.setup()` function call. Or place (potentially empty) `__init__.py` files in all the packages and use `packages=setuptools.find_packages()`.

```
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    packages=['tapify', 'tapify.Helpers', ...],
    # ...
)
```

```
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),  # make sure each package has __init__.py
    # ...
)
```